# SQL: Select distinct but adding all of one column to distinct result

Tags: laravel, function, select, eloquent

**Table Output:**

```
      data: {search_drug: search_drug},
      success: function (response){
          var tbody="";
          $.each(response.all_drugs, function (key, drug) {
          tbody+=`
                      <tr>
                          <td class="p-1">${drug.drug_name}</td>
                          <td class="p-1">${drug.drug_code}</td>
                          <td class="p-1"><p class="font-weight-bold m-0">Additional Information:</p>
                              ${drug.drug_dosage}
                          </td>
                      </tr>`;
          });

          $('tbody').html(tbody) }
```

**Controller:**

```
public function fetchdrug(Request $search_drug){

    $filter_drug = $search_drug->input('search_drug');
    $all_drugs = HmsBbrKnowledgebaseDrug::distinct('drug_code')
                                          ->when(is_null($filter_drug), function ($query) {
                                              $query->where('bbr_drug_id', '>=', 1);
                                          })
                                          //iLike is case insensitive
                                          ->when(!empty($filter_drug), function ($query) use ($filter_drug) {
                                              $query->where('drug_name', 'iLIKE', "%$filter_drug%");;
                                          })    
                                          ->groupBy('bbr_drug_id')
                                          ->get();

    return response()->json([
        'all_drugs'=>$all_drugs,
    ]);
}
```

**SQL Table:**

[image: 1]

My first goal is to `SELECT DISTINCT` the `drug_code` of my table. My problem is that the data is different under `drug_dosage` but the `drug_code` is the same.

So what I need to do in my table UI below is that under "Additional Information", I need to compile all the `drug_dosage` and place them in just one row:

[image: 2]

for example, my aim when selecting `drug_code` "CFZU", it will list down the `drug_dosage` as: "<=4 mg/L, <=3 mg/L"

How do I modify my code below so that I can select multiple of one column when I am using `SELECT DISTINCT` at the same time?

```
<td class="p-1"><p class="font-weight-bold m-0">Additional Information:</p>
    ${drug.drug_dosage}
</td>
```

Comment: try unique method instead of distinct method

Comment: error, but I still need to get all of the column `drug_dosage` in one `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`

If you didn't use DB the use it first in laravel

```
public function fetchdrug(Request $search_drug){

    $filter_drug = $search_drug->input('search_drug');
    $all_drugs = HmsBbrKnowledgebaseDrug::select('drug_code', 'drug_name', DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(drug_dosageSEPARATOR ', ') as other_detail"))
                                          ->when(is_null($filter_drug), function ($query) {
                                              $query->where('bbr_drug_id', '>=', 1);
                                          })
                                          //iLike is case insensitive
                                          ->when(!empty($filter_drug), function ($query) use ($filter_drug) {
                                              $query->where('drug_name', 'iLIKE', "%$filter_drug%");;
                                          })    
                                          ->groupBy('drug_code')
                                          ->groupBy('bbr_drug_id')
                                          ->get();

    return response()->json([
        'all_drugs'=>$all_drugs,
    ]);
}
```